# How to append variables to a string inside for loop in python?

Tags: python, string-concatenation

I am trying to append variable inside for loop `(cname[0].decode('utf-8'))`. In php we could do like this :

```
 TotalData .= ",".$cname[0];
```

How we could achieve same thing using python ?(ouput be 1,2,3,,4)

```
for cname in match:
         TotalData .= ","+cname[0].decode('utf-8');

print TotalData
```

Comment: You changed the `.` to `+` but didn't think of changing `.=` to `+=`?

Comment: Thanks.That fixed the problem i totaly forgot that i can use + in python

Comment: I must add that it would be more pythonic (and most probably faster) to do that in this way: `TotalData = ",".join((cname[0].decode('utf-8') for cname in match))` or `TotalData = ",".join(map(lambda cname: cname[0].decode('utf-8'), match))`

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

```
my_list = ['boo', 'foo']
text= 'initial_text'

for item in my_list:
    text += item
```